# CSS transistion apparently not applying

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout

I've just drafted together some custom "selectors" (actually, they're DIVs) and came across a little cosmetical issue:
I'd like a fading effect on the color with minified code, transistion doesn't seem to do the job in this case. Might I oversee anything important?

I wrote it on my own from scratch, but I don't see a valid reason to rewrite it in jQuery when CSS should be able to do the layout part on it's own.

JS-Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sA8uz/5/

Problematical line: `transistion: 0.5s;` (See CSS-Block, on line 14)

Everything else seems to work fine.

---

### **Edit:**

---

Patched version: http://jsfiddle.net/sA8uz/8/

Feel free to use wherever you want to.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I don't see how that applies here. I've rewritten it in jsFiddle and described the problem. It's **not** just a link to "my homepage".

Comment: Did I miss something?  He posted a fiddle and pointed out the problematic code.

Comment: The code should be **in the question** (for the reasons described at the other end of the link I posted above).

Comment: The broken code that I **suspected** to be broken **is part of my question** though. However, the problem is solved. It was a simple typo. So simple, that I expected everything but that. (Thanks @Adrift)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just spelt the property wrong, it should be `transition` not `transistion`

```
.myselect >div {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
margin: 0;
padding: 2px 2px 2px 20px;
color:black;
background: #eee;
transition: 0.5s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sA8uz/6/

Comment: Works like a charm now. I thought I spelt it properly. Cheers. BTW feel free to use the code if you have any need/use for it.

Comment: Vote to close: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178710/i-do-not-understand-the-too-localized-closure-of-questions

Comment: @CharlieKilian: I already have :p .. though I don't think the OP deserved a downvote considering he provided a well-written question and a jsFiddle

Comment: I've updated the initialization script, so the "active" answer is pre-selected properly. I thought I'd share that update with you, if anyone wants to use it... http://jsfiddle.net/sA8uz/8/